# Sed special characters in variable '&'

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sed

Sorry, easy question, but I can't find how to do it: I have a special char "&" in a Variables that I have to use in sed.

Example:

#The template .env

#### cat .env

MY_SECRET = VAR_MY_SECRET

export MY_SECRET="2C&ga&8M&jy3&g&WE&U"

sed -i "s|VAR_MY_SECRET|$MY_SECRET|g" .env

The new .env file

#### cat .env

MY_SECRET = 2CVAR_MY_SECRETgaVAR_MY_SECRET8MVAR_MY_SECRETjy3VAR_MY_SECRETgVAR_MY_SECRETWEVAR_MY_SECRETU

Comment: I learned a long time ago that to avoid doing any text processing in BASH and just do even the most basic scripts in Python. It's a little higher learning curve to get the subprocess module working with system commands, but it saves endless headaches in the end.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29613573#29613573) answer your question (especially the section on "Escaping a string literal for use as the *replacement string* in `sed`'s `s///` command")?

Comment: Also this question is easy to apply using sed: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern/2705678#2705678]

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Gordon Davisson should help.

Some applications that handle regular expressions support quote start `\Q` and quote end `\E` which makes it much easier to escape meta-characters. Perl - if available - handles quote start and quote end like this:

```
echo "MY_SECRET = \"VAR_MY_SECRET\"" | perl -pe "s|VAR_MY_SECRET|\Q$MY_SECRET\E|g" > .env
cat .env
MY_SECRET = "2C\&ga\&8M\&jy3\&g\&WE\&U"
```